# Ordenar alfabéticamente en base a una columna del collection c#

Tags: c#, collection

Estoy intentando ordenar alfabéticamente este collection, quiero ordenarlo en base a detail.Description, necesito hacerlo desde esta parte cuando se esta haciendo el recorrido

```
foreach (PayDetail detail in schedule.Details)
{
    dataGridView1.Rows.Add(detail.Key,detail.DocType, detail.Description, detail.Money, detail.Discounts.GetDiscountTotal(), detail.Money - detail.Discounts.GetDiscountTotal());
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esto es lo que imprime, se muestra tal cuál viene de la base de datos, pero necesito que se muestre ordenado alfabéticamente por la columna de la descripción
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Debe mostrarlo de la siguiente manera:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No he encontrado la manera de hacerlo :c espero puedan ayudarme

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Al quitar el ToList() me marca lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Y cual es el problema?

Comment: Hola @gbianchi acabo de agregar más información, quiero ordenar alfabéticamente en base a la columna de description

Answer (score 0):

Si tienes el **DataGrid** enlazado a la fuente de datos no te hace falta ir añadiendo filas con un **foreach**, haz lo siguiente:

```
var listaOrdenada = (from d in schedule.Details
                     orderby d.Descripcion
                     select d).ToList();
```

En la **variable listaOrdenada** usando **Linq**, aplicas una consulta que te va a ordenar por la **propiedad Descripcion**, por defecto se ordena ascendentemente, si quisieras ordenar descendentemente deberás poner:

```
orderby d.Descripcion desc
```

Y posteriormente esta lista ordenada la enlazas a la **propiedad DataSource** del **DataGrid**.

```
MiDataGrid.DataSource = listaOrdenada;
```

Para usar **Linq** debes poner en los usings:

```
using System.Linq;
```

**Actualización:**

**Visual Studio 2010** trabaja con **.Net 4.0**, por lo que si estás usando esta versión para abrir un proyecto hecho en una versión aún más antigua de **.Net** prueba a hacer lo siguiente:

Vas al **explorador de soluciones** y das clic derecho sobre tu proyecto, en el menú contextual que te sale escoge la **opción Propiedades**.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y te saldrá una ventana como esta:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aquí irías a la **opción Application** y en **Target framework** seleccionas un **framework** mas reciente.

Una vez hecho esto ya podrías utilizar características de este **framework** más reciente seleccionado por ti, y bien podrías usar **Linq**, lo que debes tener en cuenta que alomejor deberás cambiar código en tu proyecto, ya que al cambiar de **.Net 2.0** a otro **framework** más actual ya habrá sintaxis más nueva que deberás corregir.

Comment: tengo problemas para agregar la referencia Linq, ya puse el using System.Linq; al inicio del archivo, me pide dice que hace falta agregar una referencia pero no encuentro la referencia, estoy trabajando en una aplicación net framework 2.0 en visual studio 2010

Comment: al cambiar la versión afectaría en el funcionamiento de la aplicación? es que como es una aplicación que se creó con el net framework 2.0 no sé si afectaría, me gustaría poder resolverlo sin necesidad de cambiar de versión

Comment: @Ana, es que realmente la mejor solucion es cambiar la version, ya que con el paso de los años el .net 2.0 sera cada vez mas obsoleto y mas dificil de mantener

Answer (score 0):

Usando Linq en tu foreach puedes simplemente hacer un OrderBy() o un OrderByDescending()

```
foreach (PayDetail detail in schedule.Details.OrderByDescending(x=> x.description))
{
  ...
}
```

O con Sort() para esto Details Debe de ser un List<>

```
schedule.Details.ToList().Sort((x, y) => x.description.CompareTo(y.description));
foreach (PayDetail detail in schedule.Details)
{
  ...
}
```

Comment: estoy usando net framework 2.0 ya que es un sistema viejito, pero no encuentro la referencia para agregar Linq

Comment: mmm entonces podrias usar Sort() tu details tendria que ser un List<> te actualizo la respuesta a ver si te sirve

Comment: estos son los que estoy usando:
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Globalization;

cuando pongo lo que me dices me aparece subrayado el ToList(), te pongo la imagen en la pregunta

Comment: @Ana en .net 2.0 no se puede usar Linq, hay que buscar otra variante

Comment: @Ana pero visual studio 2010 trabaja con .net 4.0

Comment: @Ana quita el .ToList() , Sort() deberia de funcionar mientras sea un Collection, el ToList() lo agregue solo por validar que fuera lista, pero olvide completamente que es parte de Linq tambien.

Comment: @StialManstike pero si quito solamente ToList() me marca un error ¿cómo debería quedar la parte dentro del Sort()?

Comment: pero que que error te marca?

Comment: @StialManstike puse la imagen al final de la pregunta, sobre el error

Comment: Hola @StialManstike sigo teniedo el mismo problema agregué la imagen al final de la pregunta, agradecería mucho tu ayuda

Comment: Hola, parece que el compareTo te detecta el y.description como un lambda en lugar de un string, no se en realidad porque suceda eso, pero puedes calar la siguiente forma .Sort((x, y) => string.Compare(x.description, y.description)) fuera de esto, ya no creo que pudiera ayudar mas con este detalle.